# Jetpack Navigation not working despite matching ids

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I have setup a project that uses the jetpack navigation graph in a drawer layout, navigation view. The project is multi-modular thus, the navigation graphs are nested and included in the main navigation graph using `<include app:graph="">` tag. Now, an issue arises where items in one of the included graphs are clicked in the navigation view, despite having matching ids with the destination fragments, are not working, i.e not opening the respective fragments.

According to the official documentation, https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/integrations/multi-module, my problem was including the `app:startDestination` as the menu id instead of using the id of the navigation graph included.

For instance, say this is the `main_nav_graph.xml`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/home_nav_graph">
    <include app:graph="@navigation/home_nav_graph" />
    <include app:graph="@navigation/second_nav_graph" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_another"
        android:name="AnotherFragment"
        android:label="@string/another"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_another" />
</navigation>
```

And this is the `second_nav_graph.xml`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/second_nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment_start">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_start"
        android:name="StartFragment"
        android:label="@string/start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start" />
</navigation>
```

So my problem is that the menu item that is supposed to navigate to fragment start was setup like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/fragment_start"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/start" />
```

Instead of:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/second_nav_graph"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:title="@string/start" />
```

Thus when including a navigation graph you're supposed to match the id of the navigation graph and not a specific destination within the graph with the menu item.